# Are you able to set limits on the network bandwidth with Azure VMs?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, network-traffic

I'm trying to get my Azure VM resource group to only use 100GiB of going out bandwidth in a given time frame, is there any way inside of the azure portal to set these limits?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to set these limits on the Azure portal, but you can select VM sizes. Basically, Larger virtual machines are allocated relatively more bandwidth than smaller virtual machines. You have available options for your VM types such as Compute optimized, Memory optimized,  Storage optimized, GPU, High performance compute on the Azure portal.

> Expected outbound throughput and the number of network interfaces
>   supported by each VM size is detailed in Azure [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json) and [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/sizes?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json) VM
>   sizes. Select a type, such as General purpose, then select a
>   size-series on the resulting page, such as the Dv2-series. Each series
>   has a table with networking specifications in the last column titled,
>   Max NICs / Expected network performance (Mbps).

The throughput limit applies to the virtual machine. Throughput is unaffected by the number of network interfaces.

Refer to the document: [Virtual machine network bandwidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-machine-network-throughput)

Comment: ah okay yeah, I could see the data rate limit but that's annoying you can't have a data cap like with phone plans :(
Thank you though!